# Running Shiny from JupyterLab in a container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to run a Shiny app from inside a Jupyter notebook that's running in a container?

Here's some basic code. If I run this by using Visual Studio Code and [remoting into the container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) it works: I can navigate to the displayed URL in the browser and see the app.

```r
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

However, if I try to run the same code in a notebook, using the JupyterLab interface, it fails to connect:

[image: image|690x370]

[image: image|690x370]

The image is based on the standard [jupyter/datascience-notebook image](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from Docker Hub.

I also tried to specify a port number and open that port in the `docker run` command, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: publishing on ``0.0.0.0`` also doesn't work?

Comment: No, publishing on 0.0.0.0 doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

*Answering for posterity, since I encountered this same problem running my app in a jupyter notebook inside of docker. Some of this may be self evident, but why not be thorough?*

##### 1. Publish your container port with docker

Make sure that docker is publishing out your container port to your local machine using the `-p local_port:container_port` option in your `docker run` command.

In this case, I'm publishing out `8888` for my jupyterlab interface and `5749` for my shiny app.

```bash
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 5749:5749 jupyter/r-notebook:latest
```

##### 2. Set the right `host` and `port` arguments in your `runApp` call

Your `port` needs to be the one that you exposed in your `docker run` options. If you don't set this, Shiny is going to go out to a [random port between 3000 and 8000](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.4/runapp), which will not be published out of your container.

Your `host` needs to be `0.0.0.0`. This makes the ports that you exposed visible to clients outside of the machine (i.e. container) running your app. If you don't do this, then only the machine (i.e. container) running the app can see it. The outside browser porting into your container won't be able to connect. That's why you could see the app when you remoted into the container, but couldn't otherwise.

This command worked for me

```r
runExample("01_hello", host="0.0.0.0", port=5749)
```